# I want to delete my added jobs in a table

Tags: jmeter

I want to delete my added jobs in a table in JMeter. So when I try to delete in response it deletes only the first value, not the next value. I tried to use beanshell sampler but it didn't traverse to the next row to fetch the value

Answer (score 0):

A "delete" request should be some form of [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request which takes "job" position or ID as the parameter, you can see how does the "delete" request for the "job" looks like using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or recording a single request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Once you know how the request looks like and how the "job"s are being selected for deletion you should be able to:

1. Extract the job IDs (or whatever is the parameter) using a suitable JMeter's [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and store them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). The process is known as ["correlation"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations/) and there is a lot of information on the topic in the Internet
2. Use i.e. [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to send a "delete" request for each "job" instance in the "table'